# Customize Zoomable icicle using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add one image and one text area in each cell of zoomable Icicle.

I have tried something to put textbox and image on cells using `cell.append`

```
// Add an image to each cell
const image  = cell.append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "/fileV.jpg") // Change the path to your image
   .attr("width", 100)  // Adjust the width of the image
   .attr("height", 100)  // Adjust the height of the image
   .attr("x",20)
   .attr("y",300)
   .classed("img", true);

// Add a text area to each cell
const textarea = cell.append("foreignObject")
   .attr("width", 500)  // Adjust the width of the text area
   .attr("height", 100)  // Adjust the height of the text area
   .attr("x",20)
   .attr("y",1200/2)
   .append("xhtml:textarea")
   .on("blur", function(event, d) {
      // Add your onblur logic here
      console.log("Textarea blur event:", d.data.name, "value", event.target.value);
    });
```

But the problem is, Other clusters text area and image is showing on current cluster.
Is there anyway cleaner to append elements on icicle svg? also can I show somehow current cluster image and text area?
Here is the repository link for what I have tried since now [Repo Link](https://github.com/bilawal-cyber/Icicle.git)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide
[a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
, along with your desired
 results, your actual
 results, including all errors
, and demonstrate your research and your attempts
 and explain what precisely didn’t work.